# ice03 nightly build error - wix/ sln

Tags: msbuild, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3.7

I have 2 different solutions for nightly build compiling almost the same code.
I also have 2 different solutions compiling 2 different wix installers.

same *.dlls goes to different *.exe

The installers are outputing ICE03 Invalid language ID....

```
 ICE03: Invalid Language Id; Table: File, Column: Language, Key(s): filAAED19CB2C0BBE304CDB8EB1AAF7473F
```

the language ID for both is 1033. and i don't want to suppress the ICE03 warning,
at first the installer error about *.xml files and *.pdb files so i removed them from the installer. 

however now it outputs this error for *.png files which are my icons...

on my local machine both of the installers are building fine!

so i suspect the definition of the build...

has anyone come across this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for now is to suppress the ICE03 warning, it works. 
however i don't like this solution